# KSQL/KStream - Get the offset according to the producing time

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I know using Kafka consumers's api we can get an offset that corresponds to a particular timestamp (getOffsetsByTimes()).

How can we get the offset and start replaying the streams from a point based on timestamp in KSQL or KSTream?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported in KSQL yet. One option you have is to use a predicate to filter out records you don't want:

`SELECT * FROM SOURCE_STREAM WHERE ROWTIME > xxxx`

but this could be inefficient depending on where the offset is relative to the amount of data in the log.

Comment: "yet" -- Is there an issue to watch?